# Google Map API Trouble

Tags: php, geocoding

I've got some code that takes any address and returns lat and long as a php variable.

```
if ($_SESSION['where']) {
    $where = stripslashes($_SESSION['where']);
    $whereurl = urlencode($where);

$location = file("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=new+york+New+york
&output=csv&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        list ($stat,$acc,$north,$east) = explode(",",$location[0]);
        $html = "Information for ".$where."<br>";
        $html .= "North: $north, East: $east<br>";
        $html .= "Accuracy: $acc, Status: $stat<br>";
} else {
        $html = "Varibles Undefined";
}

?>


     <?php $_SESSION['lat'] = "$html"; $_SESSION['lon'] = "$whereurl"; echo"<strong>"?><?php echo "$north";?>&deg; North, <?php echo "$east";?>&deg; East</strong>
```

I know it works because when I enter

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=$whereurl
    &output=csv&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

manually into a browser, it returns

```
200,4,40.7143528,-74.0059731
```

which is what I need saved as a PHP variable. However it's not saving it as $north or $east. Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thank's in advance.

here's what it gives me:

{ "name": "new york new york", "Status": { "code": 200, "request": "geocode" }, "Placemark": [ { "id": "p1", "address": "New York, NY, USA", "AddressDetails": { "Accuracy" : 4, "Country" : { "AdministrativeArea" : { "AdministrativeAreaName" : "NY", "SubAdministrativeArea" : { "Locality" : { "LocalityName" : "New York" }, "SubAdministrativeAreaName" : "New York" } }, "CountryName" : "USA", "CountryNameCode" : "US" } }, "ExtendedData": { "LatLonBox": { "north": 40.8495342, "south": 40.5788964, "east": -73.7498543, "west": -74.2620919 } }, "Point": { "coordinates": [ -74.0059731, 40.7143528, 0 ] } }, { "id": "p2", "address": "Manhattan, New York, NY, USA", "AddressDetails": { "Accuracy" : 4, "Country" : { "AdministrativeArea" : { "AdministrativeAreaName" : "NY", "SubAdministrativeArea" : { "Locality" : { "DependentLocality" : { "DependentLocalityName" : "Manhattan" }, "LocalityName" : "New York" }, "SubAdministrativeAreaName" : "New York" } }, "CountryName" : "USA", "CountryNameCode" : "US" } }, "ExtendedData": { "LatLonBox": { "north": 40.8200450, "south": 40.6980780, "east": -73.9033130, "west": -74.0351490 } }, "Point": { "coordinates": [ -73.9662495, 40.7834345, 0 ] } } ] }

Comment: How is it related to javascript? `manually into a browser, it retruns` may be it has an empty line in front. Try to replace `file` with `file_get_contents` and remove `[0]` after `$location`

Comment: @Cheery Did both those things, still not registering the two variables.

Comment: In that case we need example of the request to google maps. Or show us the result of `var_dump($location);`

Comment: here's an example of the request url http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=new+york&output=csv&key=AIzaSyAQtiJHUt5KiL-aGONLlACQQ3OdwpbvFzI

is that what you mean?

Comment: And it works perfectly. Check what do you actually have in the script as the result of request, insert `var_dump($location);` after the line with `file` and check the output.

Comment: It means that your server is not able to make outgoing connection. Is it a free hosting? They always limit such things. Enable output of the error messages and try again.

Comment: The client set this up on yahoo small business. Which is turning out to be a major problem.

Comment: Enable errors, check what happens. May be url wrappers are disabled, try CURL in that case. But the problem is that it is not able to perform a remote request.

Comment: How would I do this using curl?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php  Only if it is available on the server. Or this example, it does not write to the file http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/curl-example.htm

Comment: Just replace URL here http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/curl-example.htm

Comment: print curl_download('http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=new+york+new+york&output=csv&key=AIzaSyAQtiJHUt5KiL-aGONLlACQQ3OdwpbvFzI');

That doesn't work either, and I know yahoo supports curl.

Comment: Did you check for error messages? May be outgoing connections are not allowed. I've checked it - everything works fine, just comment the line with `CURLOPT_REFERER`. The output was `200,4,40.7143528,-74.0059731`

Comment: It means that the hosting company disabled outgoing connections and you should ask their support about possibility of retrieval of the remote data. Example with `echo curl_download('...');` and commented line related to the referrer was also working in my local machine.

Comment: sorry to keep bugging you, I posted above what it gives me, now how would I save lat and lng as  $north and $east?

Comment: It is the data in JSON format. Use http://www.php.net/json_decode for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use file_get_contents instead (which returns you a string).

Short Example:

```
$location = file_get_contents("http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=$whereurl&output=csv");
$test = explode(",",$location);
print_r($test);
```

---

Full Solution here:

### http://www.ece.uvic.ca/~casualt/random.php?location=Bermuda

Source:

```
$theLocation = "new+york";
$locIn = $_GET['location'];
if($locIn)
{
    $theLocation = urlencode($locIn);   //Just to be safe (even though this got passed in via get
}
$location = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q='.$theLocation.'&output=csv&key=AIzaSyAQtiJHUt5KiL-aGONLlACQQ3OdwpbvFzI');
$test = explode(",",$location);
//print_r($test);
$lat = $test[2];
$long = $test[3];
echo '<h1>Magical Location of '.$theLocation.':</h1>';
echo '<ul>';
echo '<li>Longitude: '.$long.'</li>';
echo '<li>Latitude: '.$lat.'</li>';
echo '</ul>';
```

That should do the trick for you. :)

Comment: Still not working... When I echo $html it produces Information for New york, New york: , East: Accuracy: , Status: and Session Where is set properly.